# how to get lock on microphones in android phone to record calls only with my app

Tags: android

I want to make an app which can record calls.
But if there is another app for call recording than my app does not get access to microphone to record calls.
Is there any way to acquire lock on microphone so that only my app can record the calls?
Or can I check that whether there is any other app for call recording or not?

Comment: I did not find any solution yet. Please tell me if someone knows.